# Embedding a listing or directory with variables

Tags: wordpress, profile, directory

I need to create a public list from civicrm. That part is straightforwards. A profile with shortcodes into WP would work. But the list needs to be filtered by country.  So it is not practical to have a profile for every country. What is the best way to embed a public list in a WordPress page based on a profile combined with a variable for country?

Answer (score 2):

Add/edit 'Country' field to the profile and make is searchable.

[image]

This will allow you to filter the results based on country in the directory listing.

Demo: http://civi.intdms.com/civicrm/profile?gid=14&reset=1&force=1

Comment: Thanks, will try this.  Any ideas for how to embed short code with that variable so the list is included on a wordpress page that has other non-civicrm content